# Problem saving edited zip archive (docx)

Tags: php, xml, docx

So here is my code:

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.docx') === TRUE) {

 $xmlString = $zip->getFromName('word/document.xml');
 $xmlString = str_replace('$FIRST_AND_LAST_NAME', 'John Doe', $xmlString);
    $zip->addFromString('word/document.xml', $xmlString);

 echo 'ok';

    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Its purpose is simple. It opens a test.docx file, searches for all occurences of a string "$FIRST_AND_LAST_NAME" and replaces them with "John Doe".

It works perfectly on my Windows development server (the "John Doe" string is in the docuemnt when I open it).

It does not work on my Lunux production server ("$FIRST_AND_LAST_NAME" string is still there, there is no "John Doe").

There is no error or notice, the "ok" is printed without any errors. I made sure the test.docx file has priviledges set to 777.

Comment: No warnings? Error reporting is on? Does `close()` return `true`?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the contents of $xmlString after it's been extracted? Could be the extraction's failing on the Linux side of things. str_replace won't get mad at you and just suddenly fail for no reason, so most likely its input (the $xmlString) isn't what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: @Pekka I just noticed the $zip->close() returns false.

Comment: @Marc If I echo the XML string, it is correct with the "$FIRST_AND_LAST_NAME" is replaced with "John Doe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have used a class I found at phpclasses:

http://phpclasses.web4u.cz/package/6278-PHP-Edit-a-Zip-archive-in-pure-PHP-no-temporary-files.html

Here is the working code:

```
private function GenerateDocx($theTemplate, array $theReplacemenArray, $theOutputFile)
{
    $aSearchArray = array();
    foreach(range('A','Z') as $aLetter) {
        $aSearchArray[] = str_repeat($aLetter, 5);
    }
    $aArrayCountDifference = count($aSearchArray) - count($theReplacemenArray);
    $aSearchArray = array_slice($aSearchArray, 0, -$aArrayCountDifference);     

    require_once('tbszip.php');
    $tbszip = new clsTbsZip();
    $tbszip->Open($theTemplate);

    $aXmlPath = 'word/document.xml';

    if (true === $tbszip->FileExists($aXmlPath)) {

        $aXmlString = $tbszip->FileRead($aXmlPath);

        $aXmlString = str_replace($aSearchArray, $theReplacemenArray, $aXmlString);

        if (1 != $tbszip->FileReplace($aXmlPath, $aXmlString)) {
            throw new Exception('FileReplace() failed.');
        }

        $tbszip->Flush(TBSZIP_FILE, $theOutputFile);

        $tbszip->Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I know it's an old class for PHP 4 but hey, it works. And I just needed to get it work now. I can refactor later.

Answer (score 1):

If `close()` returns false, there was an error writing out the archive.

Use [`getStatusString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getstatusstring.php) to get the exact error message.

Comment: I get 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method ZipArchive::getStatusString()'. It seems the server is older version of PECL zip.

Comment: @Richard aww. Can't see any pre-5.2.7 way of getting the error message... Error reporting is turned on fully?

Comment: @Richard I can't see any documentation on the previous, PECL-based versions of ZipArchive ... No idea how they handled write errors back then. They must have somehow, but I can't see how.

Comment: It's actuall probably both PHP < 5.2.7 and also older PECL zip. It should still work though. It's not that old. The compiled PHP on server is 5.2.6. That is relatively recent.

Comment: Check if the zip file's writeable by the web server.

Comment: @Marc B I have set the file's priviledges to 777 in Filezilla. Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: @Richard no, that should be okay (plus PHP would probably raise an fopen() warning if it wouldn't work.)

Comment: @Richard have you tried doing a `print_r` on the Zip object? Maybe it has an error message set somewhere. Also, there is a function to get a class's methods (can't remember its name right now) maybe there is another method to show the error.

Comment: @Pekka I will try tomorrow. I've already left the work and am too exhausted to fiddle with this from home.

Answer (score 1):

Add `sleep(1)` before `$zip->addFromString('word/document.xml', $xmlString);`

It works on my Ubuntu 12.04

Don't forget to type your variable in same time when you create a docx file, I mean never type `FIRST_AND_LAST_NAME` and then you add a symbol `$` after that. It creates different XML code.