# how to convert xml to docx document?

Tags: php, docx

I want to create an applications that can replace specific words in docx document, I've got a function that can convert docx files into xml, the following is the function

```
function read_file_docx($filename){
    $content = '';
    if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;
    $zip = zip_open($filename);
    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;
            if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;
            $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while
    zip_close($zip);
    return $content;
}
```

This function returns the following xml data

```
<w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
    <w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="style0"/>
            <w:spacing w:after="0" w:before="0"/>
            <w:contextualSpacing w:val="false"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Nomor</w:t>
            <w:tab/>
            <w:tab/>
            <w:t>: 032/AP-DK/04/14</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    ..
```

with the results above, I can do string processing to replace specific words, the problem is how to restore xml above to docx document ?

Comment: Well, try to switch to [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/ZipArchive) class. It actually can pack file back after processing. Espeically look at [`ZipArchive::addFromString(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php). As users noted, it can overwrite same entries.

Comment: thank you @HAL9000, but when i try using $zip->addFromString() it just write the xml into docx file, can you give me an example that use docx file

Comment: okay, thanks to @HAL9000, i just need to change first parameter of $zip->addFromString() to 'word/document.xml' like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566677/problem-saving-edited-zip-archive-docx) example and it work like a charm